# Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer php GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to make post request and the post request is working but I'm not getting the response

```
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Basic ' . 'token==']]);
        $data = $client->post(
            'url',
            [
                'form_params' => [
                    'address' => 'addreww',
                    'name' => 'Zia Sultan',
                    'phone_number' => '2136000000',
                ]
            ]
        );
        return $data;
```

What I'm getting in my insomnia

```
Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this error, so to find exact issue, try adding `'debug' => true` in the request, and see what is the output of that

Comment: hi I'm getting the info with debug true. How can I access this data. Here is the output in pastebin  https://pastebin.com/pyaUwMsU.

Answer (score 1):

You're code is working, `post` method returns `ResponseInterface`, we need to fetch the content from it, we need to first fetch the `StreamInterface` by calling `getBody()` and chaining it will `getContents()` gives us the actual response. Keep `debug` mode **On**, to get find the exact error for `Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer`, and when this error occurs, share the entire trace with us

```php
try {
    $response = (new \GuzzleHttp\Client())->post(
        'url',
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . 'token=='
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'address' => 'addreww',
                'name' => 'Zia Sultan',
                'phone_number' => '2136000000',
            ],
            // 'http_errors' => false,  // Set to false to disable throwing exceptions on an HTTP protocol errors (i.e., 4xx and 5xx responses)
            // 'debug' => true,
            // 'connect_timeout' => 30 // number of seconds to wait while trying to connect to a server, Use 0 to wait indefinitely (the default behavior)
            // 'read_timeout' => 10 // timeout to use when reading a streamed body, default value is default_socket_timeout in php.ini
            // 'timeout' => 30 // the total timeout of the request in seconds. Use 0 to wait indefinitely (the default behavior).
        ]
    );

    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
} catch (Throwable $exception) {
    print_r($exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was returning the data only but I needed to return getBody() like this way

```
$data->getBody()
```

Its working now